# Executing java program on Hadoop

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, jframe

I need to execute a java program that creates a `JFrame` and do some operations on hadoop cluster. 
I exported the JAR and executed it using `hadoop jar MyFile.jar MainClass` , but the problem is that whatever is written via `System.out.println` are being printed on console ,  but the Frame is not opening whereas when I run the same program through Eclipse (via "Run on Hadoop") option the whole program is running absolutely fine.

InShort:- `JFrame` is not executing on hadoop whereas rest of output on console is executing"

Need some help in this regard.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is the instance of hadoop where the JFrame is not loading on the same machine where it works if running in eclipse? My guess is that the environment where it doesn't work is either headless or remote.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Hadoop NameNode (Where i think that your trying to run you GUI application) running on  Linux? 
Does it have some kind of Graphical User Interface? (Like KDE or Gnome),

When you "Run on Hadoop" i think that what is happening is the application is launched on your machine and on the DataNode / NameNode as the console application, or some thing like that.

Can you describe the development environment a little more?

Comment: I am running hadoop through Cygwin on windows Platform.Both the namenode and datanode are on the localhost. I just need to know why I can't get any GUI whereas Eclipse can spawn it?

Comment: I'm still not quiet sure why are you running a GUI application as a job on Hadoop.
I have never tried to do such a thing.
but my only speculation is that when you're trying to run it via eclipse, it launches that application on with the from eclipse with recognizes that you have the ability to use Grapical user interface,
and launches the application, but when running on the node Explicitly hadoop doesn't know that you do have the ability,
so it only print out to the console.

Comment: I am making an applet on which you can drag and drop a file and that file gets copied on the hadoop cluster.

Comment: OK, great, i understand it much better now,
then the actual java program should not run on Hadoop.

The execution should be an ordinary lets say Swing Application, that only runs on the Name node,
You can use the FileUtil class [link](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html)

To take the local file and copy it to the destination HDFS.

If you try to run the same program on the cluster "Run on hadoop" it will try to run it as a "Map/Reduce" job.
Does it make things more clear? or i'm not understanding your needs correctly?